# Cannot install WebEssentials - "extension not installable on ... installed products"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I just decided it was time to refresh WebEssentials.  I am running Visual Studio 2013 Pro.  I had W.E. 2013 Update 2 RC.  I uninstalled it and then tried to install the current Update 3.  It tells me I have no products that it can install on.

```
Searching for applicable products...
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell - Integrated Mode
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone
Found installed product - Microsoft **Visual Studio Professional 2013**
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
Found installed product - Global Location
Found installed product - ssms
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

Is there something left from the uninstall that is blocking a new install??  Any ideas??  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to install an update (as opposed to the full product).

Comment: This is not an incremental update; it's just the 3rd version.  I'm worried that the RC broke something.

Answer (score 7):

This is my mistake -- I read "SUPPORTS Visual Studio 2013 " but missed "Requires VS2013 **Update 3**" (my emphasis).

Answer (score 5):

WebEssentials 2013 requires Visual studio 2013 **Update 4** to be installed first.

See [The download page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361)

Answer (score 1):

Take a note of the supported versions. For older releases go to... https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything is left from the previous install that is blocking your installation of WE2013 because I had the same type of error messages when I was installing on VS2013.  Perhaps it is a bug with the RC.  I have noticed that installation of WE2013 from within VS Extensions and Updates does not give this type of error.  Perhaps you want to try that.

Comment: SO1 did not "have a different question". He did not "request clarification from an author". He was merely pointing out that since he has the same problem with a new install, the updates may not be the problem. JakeParis and Qberticus: At least read what the person said before criticizing it and subtrating a point.

Comment: @John Pankowicz - thanks for having a different and positive view of my comment.  Chris has found a solution to his problem so am happy my experience/comment may have given him an insight.

Answer (score 1):

The following solved my problem.

Install  ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update

Install Visual 2013 update 4(if you haven't already)

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-studio-2013-update