# DirectX VSIX Installer Installation Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directx, vsix

I am just beginning DirectX programming on Visual Studio Express 2013.
I searched online how to begin with it.
I found a resource [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WDC-DirectX-game-learning-7cf9bdce)

I downloaded the zip and when I ran the VSIX file I got the following error:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

And following is the Install log:

```
13-06-2015 14:04:12 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
13-06-2015 14:04:12 - -------------------------------------------
13-06-2015 14:04:13 - Initializing Install...
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - Extension Details...
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Identifier      : WDCGameTemplates..c3488525-c3e7-49c4-9619-e082f4a95772
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Name            : WDC Game Templates
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Author          : Microsoft Windows SDK
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Version         : 1.0
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Description     : Create realtime, graphics-intensive Windows Store games using DirectX and native code. Includes template code for graphics, sound effects, background music, and input.
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Locale          : en-US
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   MoreInfoURL     : 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   Supported Products : 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -           Version : [12.0,13.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -   References      : 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       -------------------------------------------------------
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Name         : Windows Software Development Kit for Windows Store Apps
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Version      : [8.1,9.0)
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 -       Nested       : No
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - 
13-06-2015 14:04:14 - Searching for applicable products...
13-06-2015 14:04:15 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
13-06-2015 14:04:15 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio  Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
13-06-2015 14:04:15 - Found installed product - Global Location
13-06-2015 14:04:15 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I also refered to the this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222180/cannot-install-webessentials-extension-not-installable-on-installed-produ)

and followed the instruction provided in each and every answer. Still I am getting the same error.

Please tell me what else I need to do to fix this.
I am totally new to DirectX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.

Downloaded Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 4.
And it worked fine.

Comment: That's correct. Express editions don't support extensibility features, but Community (and Pro+) do. The OP might want to check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) as well.